# SQL Server 2008 R2 supplied values does not match table definition - Linked Server

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-insert

I am currently migrating some processes from one server to another. However one of the processes needs to trigger on the new server, but insert a record still on the old server.

I've set a linked server up and it works fine. However when I add the linked server address in the stored procedure on the new server its throws :

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition

Despite it running perfectly on the old server.

Keep in mind the stored procedure is doing the exact same. But is using a linked server address top update the same table. Both SQL instances are the same version and everthing else is the same.

Any thoughts?

Comment: @GarethD - I run the insert query on the original server no poblem. then copy the same query into a new query windows on the new server. add the linked server prefix and run it and it trips over. Its not actaully accessing any data on the new server?

Comment: We probably need to see your table definition as well as the relevant stored procedure to help any further